# How to add authentication to URL() or JsonSlurper()

Tags: groovy, authorization, github-api, github-enterprise, github-api-v3

I have a groovy script that closes old pull requests. The part where it fetches the open pull requests worked before with an access token:

```
String json = new URL("${giteaUrl}/api/v1/repos/projectname/reponame/pulls?page=${page}&state=all" +
        "&sort=recentupdate&access_token=${accessToken}").getText()
prData = new JsonSlurper().parse(json.bytes)
```

We migrated from Gitea to GitHub Enterprise and now I need to use the `User` Header field for authorization. This is how it works with curl:

```
curl  \
  -s   \
  -f  \
  --user "username:apitoken" \
  --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --request GET "https://repourl.com/api/v3/repos/projectname/reponame/pulls"
```

I have tried:

```
String json = new URL("${gitUrl}/api/v3/repos/projectname/reponame/pulls?page=${page}&state=all" +
        "&sort=recentupdate").getText(
            requestProperties: ["User": "${gitApiUser}:${gitApiToken}"]
        )
prData = new JsonSlurper().parse(json.bytes)
```

and

```
String json = new URL("${gitUrl}/api/v3/repos/projectname/reponame/pulls?page=${page}&state=all" +
        "&sort=recentupdate").getText(
            requestProperties: ["Authorization": +
              "Basic " + "${gitApiUser}:${gitApiToken}".getBytes('iso-8859-1').encodeBase64() ]
        )
prData = new JsonSlurper().parse(json.bytes)
```

but I'm always getting a `401 - Unauthorized`. What's the correct way to add authorization to URL() or JsonSlurper()?

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct: `getBytes('iso-8859-1')`? Could you try with `getBytes('UTF-8')`?

Comment: I'm not sure about my code at all as I'm not a groovy expert ;) I tried it with `UTF-8`, but I'm also getting a 401.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the base64 encoding wrong. This is how it works:

```
def authorizationString = 
    (System.getenv('GIT_API_USER') + ':' + System.getenv('GIT_API_PASSWORD'))
    .bytes.encodeBase64().toString()

String json = new URL("${gitcUrl}/api/v3/repos/PC/pc_releases/pulls" + 
        "?page=${page}&state=all&sort=recentupdate").getText(
            requestProperties: ['Authorization': 'Basic ' + authorizationString]
        )
```